# Listagem de objetos de um dicionário no Django - Criando Modelos

Tags: django

Estou tentando aprender algo sobre Django, e uma dúvida me surgiu.

Tenho um dicionário com várias chaves e valores. A ideia é, para cada chave, exibir uma lista dos valores com checkboxes que possam ser selecionadas para executar outras tarefas adiante.

Mas não entendo como posso criar modelos e depois correlacionar as chaves com os valores utilizando checkboxes no Django, alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

não seria esta a idéia?

**model.py**

```
class BookModel(models.Model):
  title=models.CharField()

class User(models.Model):
  username=models.CharField()

class Recommend(models.Model):
  user=models.ForeignKey(User)
  book=models.ForeignKey(BookModel)
  friends=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="recommended")
```

**template.html**

```
{% for friend in friends %}

<input type="checkbox" name="recommendations" id="option{{friend.id}}" value={{friend.username}} />
<label for="option{{friend.id}}"><b>{{friend.username}}</b></label><br />

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Isto, é essa a ideia, obrigado! Uma pergunta, como poderia passar o dicionário para que estes modelos fossem preenchidos? Ainda estou meio perdido no Django e os tutoriais são bem específicos!

Comment: hummm, cara, tu precisa inserir os dados do dicionario usando o orm do django, usando o exemplo q postei ficaria mais ou menos assim user = User(username="nome").save() book = BookModel(title="titulo").save() Recommend(user=user,book=book).save() #depois de inseridos os registros, faz a consulta em Recommend.friends().values() #django é complicado de explicar, mais fica simples e rapido criar coisas com ele quando a gente pega o geito

Comment: Beleza cara, obrigado pelas dicas! Vou tentar aqui!

Comment: digamos q eu tenha o seguinte dicionario de usuarios = {"user1":"user_name1","user2":"user_name2"} dai vc cria um for nesse usuarios assim: for key,value in usuarios.items(): e para cada indice do for vc add em User assim: user = User(username=value) user.save() ...e assim por diante, vc insere o user em Recommend e pronto, depois cria uma nova função em sua view para buscar estes dados com Recommend.friends().values()

Comment: Ah sim, entendi como funciona depois de fuçar um pouco! Mas de tanto mexer fiquei com outra dúvida! Se o dicionário é do tipo {a:[f1,f2,f3], a2:[f3,f4,f5]...}, como poderia salvá-lo? Tentei utilizando este modelo mas na página de administração fico com uma coluna para selecionar a, f, e uma relação many to many. Gostaria que estivesse apenas o atributo e conseguisse relacioná-lo com os fs (são mais de um para cada atributo!). Na verdade a dúvida é como relacionar o "a" com seus "fs" de tal forma que na página de administração apareça apenas uma coluna de atributos e outra com a relação.